# Sorry to muck you about

Tags: meaning, expressions

what is the meaning of the expression "Sorry to muck you about?"
Is it informal?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is. It means to not give you what you need in time or give you trouble and is [General Reference](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/muck-about)

Answer (score 1):

It's an informal way of apologising for causing  inconvenience. Another common alternative would be "Sorry to mess you around".